# Spring ws Operation 'message' is not defined in the WSDL for this service

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-ws

Hi I'm trying to create a soap client using spring-ws. I tried whith the following code:

```
public void test1() {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();

    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri("the url of my web service");

    StreamSource source = new StreamSource(new StringReader("<message xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org\">Hello Web Service World</message>"));
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
    webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(source, result);
}
```

from http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/client.html and I got this excetion.

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Operation 'message' is not defined in the WSDL for this service
        at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:37)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:774)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:600)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:537)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:492)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:436)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:427)
        at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(WebServiceTemplate.java:417)
        at Test.test1
```

How to fix it ?

Comment: Where is the contract of the webservice you're trying to consume? What's the reason you're trying to send that specific text to that webservice?

Comment: the proble occured before the message is sent.

Comment: @Sirttas: No, the presence of SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault in the stack trace indicates that the exception is thrown because the client received a SOAP fault from the server, i.e. after sending the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solve it, in the question there is juste an exemple of a case where the error occured,

I used netcat as client and got this result:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
User-Agent: Java/1.7.0_55
Host: localhost:1234
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 154

<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><message xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org\">Hello Web Service World</message></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In this test the message was not what the server was expecting. But I understood the problem.
I thought that spring ws wasn't creating the soap envelope, so the message had two envelopes.